# $\sqrt{2} \ln \pi \approx 1.618033…$, the golden ratio. Why?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, pi, golden-ratio

$\sqrt{2} \ln \pi = 1.618892$… is approximately equal to the golden ratio $\phi = 1.618033$… . Is this just a coincidence? Could it be some kind of first-order approximation?

Comment: It's probably a coincidence since $\phi$ lives in the algebraic irrational world whereas $\sqrt{2} \ln \pi$ (most likely) lives in the transcendental world, so morally there isn't likely to be a huge relationship. $\sqrt{2}$ is just around $1.4$, so it makes sense that multiplying it by a number just larger than $1$ (namely $\ln \pi$) pushes it quite close to $\phi \approx 1.6$. Here, we have only $3$ digits of accuracy, so it's not particularly remarkable.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful responses. I figured it was kind of a silly question but fun to ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{433 \pi ^2+540 \pi+156}{304 \pi ^2+457 \pi-652}$$ is in relative error of $5.9\times 10^{-18}$%

Have fun with [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=express+1.61889252982202666846453021393980400604975509114149+through+the+golden+ratio).

Comment: That's hilarious, thanks!